# Vertically Positioning a block level element in a Relative container

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to achieve this effect:

[image: Trying to do]

and I have gotten very close, Here's what I have so far:

[**JSFIDDLE** DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/8g2B4/)

CSS:

```
.block {
            margin-top: 1em;
            position: relative;
            overflow: auto;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        .icon {
            background: #000000;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 50px;
            width: 112px;
        }
        .line {
            position: absolute;
            background: #000099;
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            z-index: -1;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            margin-left: -416px;
        }
        .text {
            /*background: #004746;*/
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: middle;
            max-width: 400px;
            float: right;
            border-left: 1px solid #000099;
            padding-left: 1em;
        }
        .text:after {
            content:"";
            background: #000099;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 1em;
            height: 1px;
        }
        .text:before {
            content:"";
            background: #000099;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 1em;
            height: 1px;
        }
        .text p {
            padding: 0 0 1em 0;
        }
        .text p:last-child {
            margin: 0;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri eu liber utroque quaestio, ei dicta quaeque sed. Civibus omnesque concludaturque vim eu, ex his nostro quodsi, graecis commune posidonium mei ad. Nam facilis alienum fastidii te, te quando euripidis usu. Torquatos consetetur suscipiantur mel eu, duo cu impedit feugait.</p>

        <p>Vocibus urbanitas suscipiantur pro ut, cu nisl nobis nonumy mel. Posse omnes urbanitas usu in, nusquam invidunt ad sed, mucius recusabo has ea. Aliquip voluptua ius eu, ex vix justo mundi, indoctum scripserit mei cu. Te sit tantas albucius probatus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My only problem is the box on the left ("icon"), needs to vertically align with the line that runs through. But the box can not be position absolute.

**RULES:**

1. Has to be responsive.
2. Needs to work from IE8 up.
3. Needs to account for the fact that the text on the right is dynamic and could grow or shrink.

Comment: What do you mean by "with the line that runs through"??? You just need to position it on the line without using absolute positioning..?

Comment: I have to ask... **Why can't the 'icon' be positioned absolutely?**

Comment: to answer the first question: yes basically i need to position the blocks 'middle' on the line.

Second Question.. Its tricky to explain.. Basically sometimes the text is smaller then the box.. so then the top of the box cuts off.

Comment: wow.. i am stupid.. min-height... uhm.. sorry everyone.. guess i actually had to write down my problem to get a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to your .icon class:

```
.icon {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -25px;
}
```

Comment: OP:But the box can not be position absolute.

Comment: good question, why not? This is indeed the way to go IMO. And for the responsive part, that is what media queries are for, and you can put it back on relative when the screen becomes to small: http://jsfiddle.net/8g2B4/11/embedded/result/

Comment: ended up basically using your solution.. with min-height.. thanks.